# Subtracting results from 2 sql queries without group by limitation

Tags: sql

```
    (SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM GameLose
INNER JOIN Game ON Game.Id = GameLose.GameID
INNER JOIN Provider ON Game.ProviderID = Provider.Id
WHERE MONTH(LoseDate)=6 AND YEAR(LoseDate)=2016
GROUP BY MONTH(LoseDate),YEAR(LoseDate),Provider.Name)
(SELECT SUM(Amount)
FROM GameWin
INNER JOIN Game ON Game.Id = GameWin.GameID
INNER JOIN Provider ON Game.ProviderID = Provider.Id
WHERE MONTH(WinDate)=6 AND YEAR(WinDate)=2016
GROUP BY MONTH(WinDate),YEAR(WinDate),Provider.Name)
```

My aim is to generate a revenue that is comprised of game wins and loses per month. The issue with the query above is that I want the calculation to be carried out per game provider by grouping the results, I get an error relating to the provider name column. How can I produce the revenue results (game wins less than game loses per month) per provider without getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It will be easier for other developers to respond your questions if you could provide metadata about your tables

Comment: The tables are very small. There are quite a few tables, but they dont contain much metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check following [SQL CTE Select](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) statement

I hope it helps

```
    ;with loses as (
        SELECT
            Provider.Id, Provider.Name, YEAR(LoseDate) Y, MONTH(LoseDate) M, SUM(Amount) as Amount
        FROM GameLose
        INNER JOIN Game ON Game.Id = GameLose.GameID
        INNER JOIN Provider ON Game.ProviderID = Provider.Id
        WHERE 
            MONTH(LoseDate)=6 AND 
            YEAR(LoseDate)=2016
        GROUP BY 
MONTH(LoseDate),
            YEAR(LoseDate),
            Provider.Name,
Provider.Id
    ), wins as (
        SELECT
            Provider.Id, Provider.Name, YEAR(WinDate) Y, MONTH(WinDate) M, SUM(Amount) as Amount
        FROM GameWin
        INNER JOIN Game ON Game.Id = GameWin.GameID
        INNER JOIN Provider ON Game.ProviderID = Provider.Id
        WHERE 
            MONTH(WinDate)=6 AND 
            YEAR(WinDate)=2016
        GROUP BY 
            MONTH(WinDate),
            YEAR(WinDate),
            Provider.Name,
Provider.Id
    )
    select
        isnull(wins.Id, loses.Id) 
    Id,
        isnull(wins.Name, loses.Name) Name,
        isnull(wins.Y, loses.Y) [Year],
        isnull(wins.M, loses.M) [Month],
        isnull(wins.Amount, 0) - isnull(loses.Amount, 0) as Net
    from wins
    full join loses
        on wins.Id = loses.Id
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer. But I got this message, Column 'Provider.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes, just add it in the SELECT field lists. I updated the query